# strange reply for a bat parsing folders

Tags: batch-file

i have a script to 
1- count the number of file+folder inside a folder (passed as argument)
2- if there is only one file in it then move this file into parent folder then delete the initial folder

```
ex start:
folder-folder1-file1
      -folder2-file21
              -file22

final:
folder-file1
folder-folder2-file21 (untouched there is more than one unique file)
              -file22 (untouched there is more than one unique file)
```

the code:

```
@echo off 
setLocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET source_file=%1
echo source file = %source_file%
set N=
REM ok
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir/b %source_file%') do (
set /a N+=1
echo DETECTED:%%a
REM echo
)
 echo Number DETECTED:!N!


if %N% gtr 1 goto end
:Moving
echo.
echo  --------------------MOVING----------------------
REM unable to get the result of the precedent for loop
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir/b %source_file%') do (
rem ok
echo native:%%a
rem STRANGE the last folder is missing !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
echo fully qualified path name:%%~fa
rem STRANGE the last folder is missing !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
echo expands to a drive letter and path only:%%~dpa
rem ok
echo expands to a file extension only:%%~xa
 if not "%%~xa" == "" (
    echo this is a file!!!
    REM MOVE "%%~fa" ..
    REM RD "%%~dpa"
)   else (
echo this is a folder ...going out

)
)
goto end2
:end
echo nothing to do...going out
:end2
pause
```

The first part works well> if there is one element > go ahead
 the second part give strange results (folder is on the desktop):
The dos window

```
source file = C:\Users\ap\Desktop\Folder                         <OK
DETECTED:file1.txt                                               <OK
Number DETECTED:1                                                <ok

 --------------------MOVING----------------------
native:file1.txt
fully qualified path name:C:\Users\ap\Desktop\file1.txt          <STRANGE does NOT exist
expands to a drive letter and path only:C:\Users\ap\Desktop\     <STRANGE "Folder" MISSING
expands to a file extension only:.txt                            <OK
this is a file                                                   <OK
```

So the moving itsefl does not work!!!
Why ?
What do i miss ?

Comment: Does the moving single file should be recursive ? Case Folder1 - Sub2 - subsub3 - file, move the file to folder 1 directly if file is single in the whole hierarchy?

Comment: what do you mean with `the _last_ folder is missing`? btw folders may have extensions too.

Comment: @Endoro: the "last folder" is missing: the bat gives:fully qualified path name:C:\Users\ap\Desktop\file1.txt  wich NOT exists the correct one is fully qualified path name:C:\Users\ap\Desktop\1fichier\file1.txt          so  the dir "1fichier" has disapeared ???

Comment: @mihai_mandis YES it should be recursive The goal is to simplify files tree by erasing one level if possible without messing all the structure  But i dont know enough scripting to make this

Comment: Do you want to erase one level and all folders beneath in that level? This will erase level 3 folders and all below it.  `for /d %%a in ("d:\folder\level1\level2\*") do rd /s /q "%%a"`

Answer (score 0):

you might try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
rem count the files
for /r %%a in (*) do set /a fcnt+=1
echo %fcnt% files

rem count the directories
for /d /r %%a in (*) do set /a dcnt+=1
echo %dcnt% directories

rem move the orphan file
for /d /r %%a in (*) do (
    set "f1=true"
    set "f2=true"
    for /f "delims=:" %%b in ('dir /b /a-d "%%~a\*" 2^>nul ^|findstr /n $') do (
        set "f1="
        if %%b gtr 1 set "f2="
    )
    if not defined f1 if defined f2 (
        for %%b in ("%%~dpa.") do (
            echo move "%%~a\*" "%%~fb"
            rd "%%~a" 2>nul
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks Endoro;
i try it a little modified, for getting parametres (one cannot miss it, because if you lauch the bat from within a dir it counts itself in parsing so the result is false (i'am right ?)
for desktop\1fichier\1fichier.txt dropping the dir "1fichier" it list 1fichier.txt (fine) but it list ALSO all the dir and subdir from the desktop (too bad)

Comment: the `desktop` is also a folder. More code is necessary in this case.

Comment: I made new tests, my first script works IF arg is NOT a folder on the desktop.  I dont know why.   I cannot achieve to make both of your script work with argument

Answer (score 0):

Count number of directories and display it.
Count number of files and display it.
Count number of files and directories (exclude parent and itself) in each folder
If number of files is 1 and no directories, move the file and delete the directory.

Updated the code to run the sequence as much as there're moves to do. It is the most simple method to move file recursively, though, maybe, not the optimal. 
I hope there'll be no folder with escape symbols in its name.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:loop
set totalMoves=0
set /p "aaa=Number of directories: " < nul
dir /B /S /AD | find /C /V ""
set /p "aaa=Number of files: " < nul
dir /B /S /A-D | find /C /V ""

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /B /S /AD') do (
    for /f %%x in ('dir "%%a" ^| find /V ":" ^| find "File(s)"2^>nul') do set nf=%%x
    for /f %%x in ('dir "%%a" ^| find /V ":" ^| find "Dir(s)" 2^>nul') do set /a nd=%%x-2
    if !nf!==1 if !nd!==0 (
        set /a totalMoves+=1
        echo Folder to execute" "%%a"
        move "%%a\*" "%%a\..\"
        rmdir "%%a"
    )
)

if !totalMoves! NEQ 0 goto :loop
```

Comment: This will fail in foreign Windows and weird file names: `file(s).txt` or `!`.

Comment: I see it works with files containing "!". Not for folders :(. For "File(s).txt" - you are right. Changed to eliminate lines with file names from dir output. So this should solve the issue.

Comment: .. it should. But do you know the OP's date format? Perhaps it has no colon in .. :/ and if he/she has a folder with the simple name `!` ? Try to avoid `delayed expansion`, if it is not really necessary.

Comment: Added moving file recursively in the tree if there's only one file there. A primitive method but hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be that only the fileNAME is known to the batch. It then assumes that the file (which is actually in the target directory) is in the current directory.

Purhaps if you were to `PUSHD` the target directory (I'll assume you know to `POPD` it later, but there's a reminder...) then the problem would disappear.

---

Hmm - The question is about `"strange reply for a bat parsing folders"`  so I believe that's been explained. Now we have  a further question `"How do I move a single file from a directory to its directory to its parent and then delete the directory if it contains only one file"`

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "moveme="
PUSHD "%~1"
FOR /f %%x IN ('dir /b "%~1" 2^>nul') DO (
 IF DEFINED moveme ECHO Too many files&pause&GOTO :eof
 SET moveme=%%x
)
IF DEFINED moveme IF NOT EXIST "%~1\%moveme%\" ECHO MOVE "%~1\*" ..
pause
```

should execute that task. The `PAUSE`s are to allow the results to be seen and should be removed after verification. The `echo` is there for testing and will need to b removed to activate the move and directory-deletion.

`moveme` is set to empty at the start. If there is one entry in the target, it gets set to that entry's name. If a second entry is encountered, then `moveme` will be defined, so the batch exits.

If there is exactly one entry and that entry is not a directoryname, the required instructions are `echo`ed.

Comment: yes i think this is a way to resolve the pb. But i am unable to write correct code for this.See my last comment we are near of the solution ...

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    rem Prepare environment
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem 1|0 to indicate that folders are not treated as files
    rem When it is 0, it indicated that there is no difference between one folder
    rem containing only one file, and one folder containing only one folder
    rem When it is 1, folders are not considered as files and simplify rules does not apply to them
    set "skipFolders=1"

    rem Determine from where to start
    set "folder=%~1"
    if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"

    rem Begin the work. 

    rem Will hold a lock on batch file to avoid undesired move/deletion of
    rem batch file or folders containing it
    < "%~f0" (

        rem Retrieve the recursive list of folders  in reverse order to work from bottom to top
        for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /ad /s /b "%folder%" 2^>nul ^| sort /r ') do (

            rem Determine the contents of the folder counting files and folders
            rem To exclude folders in the final decision, add skipFolders, so the count will
            rem not be 1 in the case of only one folder and no files
            set "contents=0"
            for /d %%c in ("%%~ff\*") do set /a "contents+=1+%skipFolders%"
            for    %%c in ("%%~ff\*") do set /a "contents+=1"

            rem Test if there is only one element in folder, so "simplification" is required
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            if !contents! equ 1 (
                endlocal

                rem Let's try to remove this level if there is no name collision on new parent
                for /f "tokens=*" %%e in ('dir /b "%%f\*" 2^>nul') do if not exist "%%~dpf\%%~nxe" (

                    rem Move selected element one level up and delete extra folder
                    move /y "%%~ff\%%~nxe" "%%~dpf" >nul 2>nul 
                    if not errorlevel 1 rd "%%~ff" >nul 2>nul || break
                    if not errorlevel 1 echo ... fold on "%%f"
                )
            ) else (
                endlocal
            )
        )
    )

    endlocal
```

Comment: thanks; IT WORKS !!!  (I begin to understand first lines). I think recursiv is not a good idea, it could mess up large dir trees.

Comment: @user3157644: it should not mess up the tree. If folders are processed, the structure will be simplified, but if folders are not processed, then only files are moved along the structure up to the point where they are intended to be (well and the tree branches are pruned). Or this is what i think. If you find or think of a undesired efect, please, post it.

Comment: first i think recursiv is necessary, but it is too powerfull for large trees, specially for the ones not created personnally and/or if an empty dir is necessary for one or another prog.       It is difficult to imagine the end result of a such prog. No file will be erased (fine) but tree strurtures are sometime much harder to reconstruct (in my case especially for include files in scripts). nice code anyway.